# Base64 encoding and equal sign at the end, instead of A (base64 value of number 0)

Tags: base64

According to wikipedia:

> When the number of bytes to encode is not divisible by three (that is,
>   if there are only one or two bytes of input for the last 24-bit
>   block), then the following action is performed:
>
> Add extra bytes with value zero so there are three bytes, and perform
>   the conversion to base64.

However, if we got an extra `\0` character at the end, the last 6 bits of the input have a value of 0. And the number 0 must be base64-codified as `A`. The character `=` doesn't even belong to the base64 encoding table.

I know that those extra null characters doesn't belong to the original binary string, so, we use a different character (`=`) to avoid confussions, but anyway, the Wikipedia article and other thousand sites doesn't say that. They say that the newly constructed string must be base64-encoded (sentence which strictly implies the use of the transformation table).

Are all of these sites wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sequence of four characters chosen from the main base64 set will represent precisely three octets worth of data.  Consequently, If the total length of the file to be encoded it will be necessary to either:

1. Allow the encoded file to have a length which is not a multiple of 4.
2. Allow the encoded file to have characters outside the main set of 64.

If the former approach were used, then concatenating of files whose length
was not a multiple of three would be likely to yield a file that might
appear valid but would contain bogus information.  For example, a file
with length 32 would expand to ten groups of four base64 characters plus
three more for the final pair of octets (total 43).  Concatenating another
file with length 32 would yield a total of 86 characters which might look
valid, but information from the second half would not decode correctly.

Using the latter approach, concatenation of files whose length was not a
multiple of three would yield a result that could be unambiguously parsed
or, at worst, recognized as invalid (the base64 Standard does not regard
as valid a file that contains "=" anywhere but at the end, but one could
write a decoder that could process such files unambiguously).  In any case,
having such a file be regarded as invalid would be better than having a file
which appeared valid but which produces incorrect data when decoded.

Comment: I'm not asking how base64 encoding actually works, I know it, but why it's universally explained as: "add nulls and encode it", when it's actually translated to, "add equals", when an "equal" is not the base64 encoding of the number 0 (which contradicts the afirmation "encode it"). If you misundertood my question because of my English, tell me and I'll improve the wording.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: When encoding one or two bytes, the number of bits in the encoded form will exceed the number of bits of original input data; the purpose of the spec is to say how the excess bits should be treated.  It's not necessary that the encoder actually append nulls, process the last "triplet", and then replace one or two "a"'s with equals signs, but that's the simplest way of describing how 8 or 16 bits should be mapped onto 12 or 18.